# LDAP server migration from Debian to Ubuntu Error

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, debian, ldap, slapd

We are trying to migrate ldap from an outdated Debian server to a Ubuntu server. All attempts at using slapcat, modifying the config manually, and other tricks have failed. I believe the old database uses the bdb structure, which from researching I have found that it is not supported anymore.

The steps we took during the migration are as follows:

Backed up and copied the old ldap database using slapcat.

```
sudo slapcat -n 0 -l config.conf
sudo slapcat -n 1 -l database.ldif
```

We have then installed and dpkg-reconfigured slapd on the new server, to match the installation specification of the old one.

Following this, we would use slapadd to recover the old database.

```
sudo slapadd -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -n 0 -l config.conf
```

Which produced the following error

```
slapadd: could not add entry dn="cn=config" (line=1):
Closing DB...
```

The next command we try to restore the database.

```
sudo slapadd -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -n 1 -l database.ldif
```

But again received multiple errors:

```
mdb_id2entry_put: mdb_put failed: MDB_KEYEXIST: Key/data pair already exists (-30799) "dc=cs"
=> mdb_tool_entry_put: id2entry_add failed: err=-30799
=> mdb_tool_entry_put: txn_aborted! MDB_KEYEXIST: Key/data pair already exists (-30799)
slapadd: could not add entry dn="dc=cs" (line=1): txn_aborted! MDB_KEYEXIST: Key/data pair already exists (-30799)
Closing DB...
```

At this point we experienced errors with loading the config file. We attempted to convert it from bdb to mdb architecture but we would still end up with errors while loading the database.ldif file.

Would anyone have a reliable method for migrating the ldap database to a new server? As most guides are very outdated.

Comment: The actual error messages you encounter the software versions involved would be helpful.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Sorry about that, I've just updated the post with the errors we experienced.

Comment: What is the old version of slapd? What's the new version?

Comment: Old version was 2.4, thank you but I was able to solve this issue last night! Posted an answer in case anyone else struggles with something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the outdated database backend on most of the old slapd systems (<2.4.x). Converting manually to hdb/bdb => mdb fixes these issues on new slapd versions.

```
sudo slapcat -n 0 -l config.conf
sudo slapcat -n 1 -l database.ldif
```

Make sure to turn off slapd service.

```
service slapd stop
```

Replace all hdb/bdb references with mdb in the config.conf and database.ldif files.

Before using slapadd to load the config, empty the slapd.d directory.

```
rm -rf /etc/ldap/slapd.d/*
```

Then load your updated mdb config.

```
slapadd -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -n 0 -l config.conf
```

Next make sure to empty the ldap directory as well.

```
rm -rf /var/lib/ldap/*
```

Now load in the converted mdb database.

```
slapadd -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -n 1 -l database.ldif
```

Give openldap permission to the slapd.d directory.

```
chown -R openldap:openldap /etc/ldap/slapd.d
```

Start slapd service, you should now have a migrated ldap database.

```
service slapd start
```

Confirm with slapcat

```
slapcat -n 0
slapcat -n 1
```